# How to Send a document via Telegram Bot API

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I wanted to send a Document via Telegram bot API and my document is stored locally. I tried:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botToken/sendDocument?chat_id=-5278798&document=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\file.txt
```

But I got Error...

> `Bad Request: failed to get HTTP URL content`

This method only works in remote URLs, how to send documents via bot API?

Comment: Show some code so we can figure out what went wrong. Maybe it's the Python module that's having a bug?

Comment: I just made a GET request for now .to Check weather this method works or not

Answer (score 2):

Using [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) you can send a local file using `send_document` method

```
 c_id = '000011'   
 filename = '/tmp/googledoc.docx'

 context.bot.send_document(chat_id='c_id, document=open('googledoc.docx', 'rb'), filename="googledoc.docx")
```

Comment: It should be noted that his solution applies if OP uses the `python-telegram-bot` library which they tagged but don't use in their example code

Comment: Good point, I edited my answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use files local from your pc as I assume you have done via the `document=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\file.txt` in your URL
On the docs it states "Pass a file_id to send a file that exists on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL for Telegram to get a file from the Internet."  [Telegram media Documents](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inputmediadocument.html)
Meaning you either have to use a file on the telegram servers or upload it to a website and send it via the URL you have uploaded it too.

Comment: So there is No way to send a file by a local storage

Comment: By scanning over the documentation it did not specify about using local files, however they did state about using a web-file or using a file already existing on the telegram servers.